# swift autoLayout overrides CGRectMake

Tags: swift, autolayout, size-classes, ios-autolayout, cgrectmake

I did not define any constraints in my storyboard, just dragged and dropped some text fields and buttons. I'm trying to update their sizes and locations programmatically. I refer them `IBOutlets` and try to update them in `viewDidLoad()` function by using `CGRectMake()`. My text fields and buttons appear on the locations according to the storyboard. Again, those locations are random, I don't have any constraints defined.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue without disabling the `autoLayout` classes? It requires much more work for this project.

Comment: `viewDidLoad` is the wrong place to do manipulate any layout information.

Comment: `CGRectMake()` just creates a structure which holds four numbers. That's it. That's all it is. It doesn't ***do*** anything. It's basically irrelevant for your issue. Presumably, what you meant to tell us is that you're setting the `bounds` or `frame` property of the view. That would be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

If you add your views in a storyboard, constraints are *always* defined. If you don't add them, they will be added automatically during compilation.

If you really want no constraints for a view, paradoxically you will have to add them and then check:

[image: Remove At Build time]

for every constraint you don't want to be exported.

Then in code you will have to set [translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) to `true` for every such view otherwise its `frame` will be ignored.

Comment: Or just, you know, turn off autolayout for the whole storyboard file.

Comment: @ken-thomases that's a bit radical :) most of the times you don't want to turn off autolayout completely.

Comment: This isn't most of the time. The questioner is clearly not prepared to use autolayout for this storyboard. It's not magic. There's no curse that befalls you if you turn it off. If you don't plan to use it, turning it off is the simple and right thing to do. Going to a great deal of effort to thwart it as you suggest is far worse.

Comment: @KenThomases Let's say you have 20 views in your storyboard and you want to use autoresizing for 2 of them. Then switching off autolayout is a very bad idea, especially if you want to support different size classes (which is a must nowadays). Then the options you have are 1. create and setup the view in code 2. Use constraints as placeholders and turn on autoresizing in code. Turning off autolayout completely is radical because it will bring a lot of problems (labels won't have correct frames, scrollview won't have `contentSize` set automatically and so on).